# How can I start drawing from a specific place in Python turtle?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I'm trying to draw grass and I'm struggling to make my drawing start from the bottom left then go all the way to the bottom right. I know there is something wrong with my code but can't figure it out.

The code I have starts from the middle and that's not what I want.

```
import turtle
import random

window = turtle.Screen()
bob = turtle.Turtle()
window.bgcolor("white")
window.title("TURTLE")
bob.pencolor("green")

window.colormode(255)


position = 0
height = 0
height11 = 0
height12 = 0
height13 = 0
height14 = 0
def draw_grass(bob):
    green = random.randint (100, 200)
    length = random.randint(10,20)
    bob.fillcolor(0,green,0)
    bob.begin_fill()
    bob.setheading(90)
    for i in range (2):
        
        bob.forward(length)
        bob.right(90) 
        bob.forward(3)
        bob.right(90)
    bob.end_fill()
    bob.penup()
    bob.pendown()
    return length
for i in range (10):
    height = draw_grass(bob)
    position = position + 3
    bob.goto(position, 0)
    if height == 11 :
        height11 = height11 + 1
    elif height == 12:
        height12 = height12 + 1
    elif height == 13:
        height13 = height13 + 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to understand that the origin `(0, 0)` is in the center of the window and you have to work with positive and negative numbers.  The screen methods `window_width()` and `window_height()` are useful for figuring out the size of a window that you didn't configure yourself.  Here's a rework of your code that incorporates these ideas:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle
from random import randint

def draw_grass(turtle):
    green = randint(100, 200)
    length = randint(10, 20)
    turtle.fillcolor(0, green, 0)

    turtle.begin_fill()

    for _ in range(2):
        turtle.forward(3)
        turtle.left(90)
        turtle.forward(length)
        turtle.left(90)

    turtle.end_fill()

    turtle.penup()
    turtle.pendown()

    return length

screen = Screen()
screen.bgcolor('white')
screen.title("TURTLE")
screen.colormode(255)

turtle = Turtle()
turtle.pencolor('green')
turtle.speed('fastest')  # because I have no patience

turtle.penup()
turtle.setposition(6 - screen.window_width()//2, 12 - screen.window_height()//2)
turtle.pendown()

height11 = 0
height12 = 0
height13 = 0
height14 = 0

while turtle.xcor() < screen.window_width()//2 - 6:
    height = draw_grass(turtle)

    if height == 11:
        height11 += 1
    elif height == 12:
        height12 += 1
    elif height == 13:
        height13 += 1
    elif height == 14:
        height14 += 1

    turtle.forward(3)

screen.exitonclick()
```